# Efficient way to fill pandas cells on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
  col1 col2
0    a    A
1    a
2    a    A
3    a
4    b
5    b
6    c    A
7    c
```

I want to search for `col1` values which have at least `N` corresponding `col2 == 'A'` values. In such cases, I want to fill in the rest of corresponding cells in `col2` column with `'A'`s.

Let's see a concrete example. Let's suppose that `N=1`. In this case, we check if there is at least one `'A'` in `col2` for the various `col1` values. For `col1='a'`, there are 2 `'A'`s in `col2`, hence this case meets the condition. Let's thus fill rows with index 1 and 3 in `col2` with `'A'`s. Moving on, we see that for `col1='b'`, there are no `'A'`s in `col2`, hence no need to fill anything here. Lastly, we see that for `col1='c'` there is exactly one `'A'` in `col2`. As this also meets the condition, we will fill in row with index 7 in `col2` too with `'A'`.

Similarly, when the `N` threshold was set to 2, new `'A'`s would only be added to rows with index 1 and 3 in `col2`, but not in the last row (index 7).

I am assuming there might be an efficient, vectorized way to go about this. For now, I could only think of iterating through the dataframe, which doesn't scale well for my original dataset with 10s of thousands of rows.

This is what I tried so far. This works for the `N=1` case, although I didn't manage to figure out how to generalize it to any `N` thresholds, let alone how to perhaps implement this more nicely:

```
df = df.sort_values(['col1','col2'], ascending=[True,False]).reset_index(drop=True)
for idx, row in df.iloc[1:,:].iterrows():
    if df.loc[idx,'col1'] == df.loc[idx-1,'col1'] and df.loc[idx,'col2']=='' and df.loc[idx-1,'col2']!='':
        df.loc[idx,'col2'] = df.loc[idx-1,'col2']
```

Code to reproduce dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['a','A'],['a',''],['a','A'],['a',''],['b',''],['b',''],['c','A'],['c','']], 
    columns=['col1','col2']
)
```

Comment: Yes, but after the `sort_values()` it would no longer be at the bottom :)

Comment: To get more answers, please remember to include a sample of the output you expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
N = 1
value = 'A'

df.loc[df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x: sum(x == value) >= N), 'col2'] = value

print(df)

  col1 col2
0    a    A
1    a    A
2    a    A
3    a    A
4    b     
5    b     
6    c    A
7    c    A
```

... then with `N = 2` ...

```
  col1 col2
0    a    A
1    a    A
2    a    A
3    a    A
4    b     
5    b     
6    c    A
7    c
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that avoids lambda functions:

```
N = 1
V = 'A'

df['col2'] = df['col1'].map(df.groupby('col1')['col2'].value_counts().swaplevel()[V].ge(N).map({True:V})).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  col1 col2
0    a    A
1    a    A
2    a    A
3    a    A
4    b     
5    b     
6    c    A
7    c    A
```